# Query posts custom field: check list inside a ACF repeater

Tags: mysql, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to query all posts that have a specific check box selected inside a repeater field.

I found this [tutorial](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-field) and what I want to do is a mix of topic 3 and 4, but I couldn't accomplish by my self, my first attempt was to query all posts and print just one checked item:

```
<?php 

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'modalidade',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

?>


<?php

// check if the repeater field has rows of data
if( have_rows('horarios') ):

    // loop through the rows of data
    while ( have_rows('horarios') ) : the_row();

        $dia_da_semana = get_sub_field_object( 'dia_da_semana' );
        $horario = get_sub_field_object( 'horario' );

        if ( in_array(1, $dia_da_semana['value'])) {
            echo 'segunda';
            print_r( $horario['value']);
            echo '<br>';
        }

    endwhile;

endif;

?>
```

But don't think that is a good solution. Maybe there is a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Please update your question to include your relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and details of what you have tried so far and why its not working.

Comment: done! thanks for the alert!

Comment: Where is your WP Query?

Comment: I'm just querying all posts of a CTP, I added in the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the tutorial found [here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-field) and tweked my code and my data structure a little bit and made it. The final code looks like this:

```
// filter
function my_posts_where( $where ) {

$where = str_replace("meta_key = 'time_%", "meta_key LIKE 'time_%", $where);
    return $where;
}

add_filter('posts_where', 'my_posts_where');

// args
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'class',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'time_%_day_of_week',
            'value'     => 'monday',
            'compare'   => 'LIKE'
        ),
    )
);
```

One change that was very important to me was to replace the `'numberposts'  => -1,` to `'posts_per_page' => -1,` to get all the posts. The property `numberposts` wasn't working.